C++ - Batching multiple header files into one
I'm working on a basic game engine, been following the advice to include only what i need. I'm noticing that at places I'm including ton of stuff from certain modules, like Math or Render. And then one is supposed to maintain these long lists regularly so it is really only what one needs, no less no more.
But is it really that big deal to include stuff I don't need? Can't I just include Render.hpp and Math.hpp where I use render and math stuff and be done, instead hunting down all the headers for every little component separately and maintaining a long list of includes? The professional advice is to always only include what I need, but then most libraries I use, they are included either by one include or separately their major modules, but not all their headers one by one.
Does including more than I need really create such a mess and increase compile/parse time so much?

"Does including more than I need really create such a mess and increase compile/parse time so much?..." It all depends on the project you use. You already seem to know that you should include only headers that are really necessary.

There is no universal answer here. This also seems unclear/unfocussed without a [mcve]. If the increase in compiling/parsing time is significant then just include the headers that are really necessary.

If it's a mess then you should simplify. There is no universal answer here, it depends on the situation, and even then in the same situation different programmers will have different opinions. Go with what you feel is best.

As I said, Ive been following the advice of include only what you need, no more no less. People give that advice as if it's a hard-rule but then I guess there can be balance. as long as there is no significant increase in mess and compile time. Is that correct?

Indeed rule of thumb, include only what you really need, forward declare what you can. In the end it is mostly about compilation time the more (unecessary) files you include the more time is spent on compiling.

The increase in compile time gets relevant in large code bases (companies).

Compile time also increases when header files are picked up from somewhere else on the network.  If one of these network files is in your common list, you will see a significant increase.  For instance, our builds used to take 1 hour.  Someone added a network header file and the build time increased to 23 hours!

@PepijnKramer I already know that it is the standard advice. But in the real world, I'm including many libraries with a single include. Or their major components separately. They are designed to be included that way. If I had to hunt down every little component one by one, and maintain the long list of includes, that is also a tradeoff. Wasted human time vs wasted compile time, i guess.

You use libraries the way they are designed to be used. If a library supplies a single header file which just includes other headers, and that header is being shown in the documentation/examples that come with the library, then it is meant to be used that way. Only use more granular headers if you really need them, e.g. to cut down compilation times. Just don't include standard library headers, or headers from other libraries, if their facilities are not used in your TU.  (All of this is a matter of opinion)

I agree with @n.m.couldbeanAI (primarily follow the docs of the library, because they may add details in later releases) and yes it is an engineering choice in the end. Tradeoff between maintainability and costs (more granular includes or compile time).


The professional advice is to always only include what I need

This is an advice, do not blindly apply it, understand why it exists so you don't go into extremes such as overusing object oriented programming and design patterns that led to lot of horrid codebase in lot of companies. Drinking water is good practice but drinking too much lead to death.
The downside of including more headers is increased compilation time (and namespace pollution in C or if you misused using namespace). This is only an issues on large projects or huge dependencies such as <Windows.h> and their feature exclusion #defines.
I would say that importing stuff unrelated to your code is bad practice and may violate logical separation, a backend agnostic game engine will never import D3D12 or Vulkan headers outside parts that are backend specific.
By what you are saying, it look like having multiple thematic header files with a bunch of includes would make your project more maintainable and less a hassle, the trade-off is probably worth the increased compilation time, especially if you loose more time to figure out the exact header listing and the higher risk of mistakes in maintaining this listing.
All big game engines actually have a few if not a single "Math.h" with all the regular linear algebra and more they use. Same for their various modules.
You already identified Math and Render as modules that may deserve their own header in your question, you may create -internal.h variants for the #includes commonly used inside these modules that should not be publicly exposed to other modules using it.

So. In C and C++, #include is literally a copy-paste of the included file content. Having a file with only #includes is common to create thematic headers. You should think about what you commonly include and define comprehensive scopes for each header in order to keep your project maintainable.
What matter ultimately is soundness (see my example about Vulkan/D3D12) and that you spend less time solving issues, waiting for and suffering about your #includes.

In my opinion, answer to this question depends of whether we are talking about .cpp or .h files.
For .cpp files only downside to include more than strictly necessary is increase of compilation time. Depending of your project and included files it can range from negligible to significant.
Completely other story if we are talking about header files. If you include not needed files here, you can introduce non needed dependencies and that can be bad for more reasons.
For example, let say your had following files:
// a.h
...
#include <some_lib_1.h>

// declare stuff for a

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
...
// define stuff for a

// b.h
...
#include <some_lib_2.h>

// declare stuff for b

// b.cpp
#include "b.h"
...
// define stuff for b

and so on, and then you decided to combine all headers:
// common.h
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

and use this common.h in all you .cpp files instead of individual includes.
Now, suddenly a.cpp has not needed dependency to some_lib_2 and b.cpp has dependency to some_lib_1.
This may require changes in your build configuration and increase complexity of different future tasks, like unit testing, refactoring etc.
